# Angular IDE with components completition

Tags: ide, angularjs, autocomplete

I am trying to solve problem with code completition using Angular 1 components. Here is a very simple code:

```
export default angular.module('gridService', [])
    .component('grid', {
        templateUrl: 'services/gridService/grid.tpl.html',
        controller: GridController,
        bindings: {
            items: '='
        }
    })
    .name;

function GridController() {
    this.omg = 'wtf';
    //this.items is not autocompleted
}
```

Is there an IDE, that would autocomplete binded `items` in the controller? I have already tried: WebStorm (configured according to their blogpost), Brackets, SublimeText2, Eclipse, Angular IDE, IDEA and my trusty PSPad :) None of them seems to be able to autocomplete this kinda trivial thing.

I mean come on, where is the problem? If the IDE has support for Angular, then it should be able to read its syntax, and here I just declare, that for `grid` component I am using `GridController` function and I am binding `items` property. Why it can't autocomplete `items` inside the controller? Is there some technical issue I just can't see that is making this problem unsolveable?

Not to mention that there is absolutely NO support for autocomplete components in templates. I mean yeah, the IDE can autocomplete the component name, so in this case I can write `gr` + Ctrl + Space and it autocompletes `<grid></grid>`, but inside `grid` template (which is again defined in component syntax) I have zero autocomplete. In Angular there is default binding to controller in component to `$ctrl` (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component), so the IDE CAN link the `$ctrl` in template I am in with according component and its controller.

So, back to my first question, can you recommend me IDE that can autocomplete this?

Comment: You might have to write your own scripts for this

Comment: Yeah I was hoping not to :)